# Mount Azure Data Lake Storage to Windows VM file system

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is it possible to mount folders in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 1 to the file system of a Windows Virtual machine, so these folders can be opening like normal folders in Windows?

Comment: hi,check the answer below

Comment: Thank you @Anass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 1 or 2 is based on  Azure Blob storage. You can mount it use free tools rclone as I describe in this article similar to AWS S3.

https://builtwithcloud.com/how-to-mount-amazon-s3-bucket-as-a-network-drive-on-windows-with-free-tools/

Rclone: is a command line program to sync files and directories to and from multiple cloud storage including AWS,Azure Blob, Google Cloud
https://rclone.org/

WinFSP: windows file systm proxy to be able to mount the folders as drive.

NSSM : to install rclone mount as service

Comment: I did not get if I can mount only blob storage or Gen1 too? In rclone I found only mount for Blob storage. My files are stored in Gen1. I am a total newbie in Azure.

Comment: Gen1 is blob storage so the same will apply